# Can you use dynamic comparator in place of static comparator and vice versa?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, comparator

According to [the book](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=11BtDwAAQBAJ&pg=SA5-PA9&dq=dynamic%20vs%20static%20comparators&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib9pSjgcP1AhWD-mEKHTueCmgQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=dynamic%20vs%20static%20comparators&f=false), there are two types of comparators, static comparator and dynamic comparator. 
The dynamic comparator has clock.

So can you use dynamic comparator in place of static comparator and vice versa assuming that they have same speed?  There is no specific application so I'm wondering about the use in general. Or is there some limitation of each when you think about its application?

Static comparator:

[image]

Dynamic comparator:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could enable a dynamic comparator full-time but it would not be plug-compatible yet functionally equivalent as a static converter with the extra pin.  Visa versa is not possible unless a flip flop is added.

Dynamic Comparators are often used in [high speed ADC'](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=dynamic+comparator+applications&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=M8PqYZHMMuKekPIP0Zgw&ved=0ahUKEwjRsbaIh8P1AhViD0QIHVEMDAAQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=dynamic+comparator+applications&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BAghEApQrQhY4hxgoB9oAHAAeACAAVGIAd0HkgECMTWYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books)s, State Machines and nanotube R&D components for example.